# Filling shapefile polygons with a color in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapefile, matplotlib-basemap

I am searching way to fill polygons of a shapefile based on a value.
So far from basemap tutorial (http://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shapefile.html) i 've found how to fill the polygons with a specific color.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pypyodbc
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
import numpy as np
 
fig= plt.figure()
ax= fig.add_subplot(111)
m=Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=34.5,llcrnrlon=19,urcrnrlat=42,urcrnrlon=28.5,resolution='h')
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
m.fillcontinents(color='#ddaa66',lake_color='aqua')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.readshapefile('nomoi','nomoi')

patches   = []

for info, shape in zip(m.nomoi_info, m.nomoi):
    if info['ID_2'] == 14426:
        patches.append( Polygon(np.array(shape), True) )

ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(patches, facecolor='m', edgecolor='k', linewidths=1., zorder=2))

plt.show()
```

What I would like to do is taking values from a dictionary such as this:

```
dict1={14464: 1.16, 14465: 1.35, 14466: 1.28, 14467: 1.69, 14468: 1.81, 14418: 1.38}
```

in which the keys are the info['ID_2'] column from the shapefile as in the code presented above and the values are the variable that i want to represent to color. Meaning to have a colormap varying from 1.16 to 1.81 and each polygon (ID_2) to have a color related to it's value from dict1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do I get the nomoi shapefile from?

Comment: I don't know where to upload it i hope this works https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Q47l1uSomLyDrHG2mxMiK3solsmWwcOd

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you want to produce a choropleth plot in basemap.
To this end you need a colormap `cmap` and a normalization `norm` in order to map values to colors, `cmap(norm(val))`. For each shape one may than set the `Polygon`'s color to the respective color from the dictionary, in this case `cmap(norm(dict1[info['ID_2']]))`.

Inside the `PatchCollection` the `match_original=True` needs to be set to keep the colors from the original polygons.

At the end it may be useful to produce a colormap from the colormap and the normalization.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import numpy as np

fig= plt.figure()
ax= fig.add_subplot(111)
m=Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=34.5,llcrnrlon=19,
                           urcrnrlat=42,urcrnrlon=28.5,resolution='h')
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
m.fillcontinents(color='w',lake_color='aqua')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.readshapefile('data/nomoi/nomoi','nomoi')

dict1={14464: 1.16, 14465: 1.35, 14466: 1.28, 14467: 1.69, 14468: 1.81, 14418: 1.38}
colvals = dict1.values()

cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu
norm=plt.Normalize(min(colvals),max(colvals))

patches   = []

for info, shape in zip(m.nomoi_info, m.nomoi):
    if info['ID_2'] in list(dict1.keys()):
        color=cmap(norm(dict1[info['ID_2']]))
        patches.append( Polygon(np.array(shape), True, color=color) )

pc = PatchCollection(patches, match_original=True, edgecolor='k', linewidths=1., zorder=2)
ax.add_collection(pc)

#colorbar
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
sm.set_array(colvals)
fig.colorbar(sm, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]