# Colour plotting certain cities in a country with basemap and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I want to show a map of each cities/district having a certain value as the variable for colour.
I have a list of cities and their corresponding values;

```
cities = [["Auckland City",5],
          ["Opotiki District",10],
          ["Kaikoura District",15],
          ["Christchurch City",25]]
```

I was hoping to fill colours of the cities based on a polygon shape, from a shape file taken from; https://koordinates.com/layer/1247-nz-territorial-authorities-2006-census/

But i cant seem to figure out a way to do it, or find similar cases/examples. 
I have only managed to draw a map of NZ with its boundaries with;

```
map = Basemap(llcrnrlon = 166, llcrnrlat = -47.4,
              urcrnrlon = 178.6, urcrnrlat = -34,
              resolution  = 'i', projection = 'lcc'
              ,lat_1=-37.5,lat_2=-44.5,lon_0=173, lat_0=-41)

# load the shapefile, use the name 'states'
map.readshapefile('nz-territorial-authorities-2006-censusWGS84', name='states', drawbounds=True)
```

P.S. I also used this to transform the shapefile i downloaded, from having map projection coordinates to geographic coordinates;

```
import geopandas as gpd

tmp = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('nz-territorial-authorities-2006-census.shp')

tmpWGS84 = tmp.to_crs({'proj':'longlat', 'ellps':'WGS84', 'datum':'WGS84'})

tmpWGS84.to_file('nz-territorial-authorities-2006-censusWGS84.shp')
```

Comment: Could this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48520393/filling-shapefile-polygons-with-a-color-in-matplotlib

Comment: yes, definitely @Riebeckite . I noticed that basemap was so vast, so i wasnt exactly sure what to search up, and this definitely helps! Thank you!